# Debug apk is working fine but after sign it and generate release apk , its showing a white blank screen in cordova ionic project

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, apk, release

I have created a debug apk by running "ionic build android" and then signed the apk with keystore file and password and ran " ionic build android --release" . now the release apk is not working in android jellybean (only showing white blank screen) but its working in android lolypop .

there is no error in console.

cordova version is 4.2.0
 cordova-android version is 3.6.4

I don't have cordova whitelist plugin in my project . if i tried to install whitelist plugin it says plugin dosen't support this cordova-android version.

My projects has "access origin = "*" in config.xml and

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" &

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"    in manifest file

Any update regarding the issue will be welcomed .

Comment: There could be many possible problems. can you show the list of js files you included and also in what sequence you include them?

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall unsigned apk before installing signed apk?

Comment: yes @Dhruv i have uninstalled the existing app and then installed the new signed and zip aligned apk . its almost two days and still no luck

Answer (score 3):

OK I got the problem and solved it . I am sharing this for one who will face the same problem in future

Actually I was using material design and injected "ionic-material" in the main module in app.js file . Somehow it won't work in pre-lolypop version . I also don't know the exact reason why it dosen't throw an error in debug version but in release version. What I did just removed the ionic-material from my project and modified my code accordingly and it ran in every version of android . I should work on how can I implement material design in pre-lolypop version also but that is another story .  Thank you .

Comment: hello,I am getting blank white screen and bunch of uncaught reference errors on android version 4.4.4.It is working perfectly on lollipop. I need to run this on Kitkat . Did you find any solution to make it work on pre lollypop?

Comment: I'm having the same issue but not having to do with ionic-material. Do you think its probably caused by an import(s) in my app.module?

Answer (score 1):

Once your app is signed, Android does not write any log for this app (i think that is for security reasons.)

Only unsigned apps can be debugged. Imagine that your production APK can be debugged, every user could connect their phones to the computer and know what really is happening inside.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply . so the weird thing is the released apk is not working in android 4.4.2 but its working on the greater version . so what could be the possible reason for that

Answer (score 0):

here is how I include my js files

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="lib/popup.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zachsoft/Ionic-Material/master/dist/ionic.material.min.js"></script>  


<script src="lib/ion-md-input/js/ion-md-input.min.js"></script>

<script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ionic-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ionic-push.js"></script>
<script src="lib/PushNotification.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ng-map.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular_google_map.js"></script>
<script src="lib/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
<script src="ngautocomplete.js"></script>


<!--  app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
```